# Generating a div that ignores all other CSS and uses only its own

Tags: php, html, css, header

I'm including a div header inside many of my webpages, and they all have vastly different stylesheets. This causes the header to undesirably inherit some parent attributes of the pages (font colors, font, etc.) on every different kind of page. How can I make it so that the div only takes CSS that applies to it, and ignores all other CSS?

Here's my CSS code: http://slexy.org/view/s213FFrREw

Here's my HTML code: http://slexy.org/view/s2sec0La7c

Answer (score 3):

You can include and modify [reset.css](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) to use your unique class names or IDs.

Answer (score 1):

To any element statements in your CSS, add the header id to them.

As a plain-text example (not using your ids)

`#header { width:100%; background-colour:#f00; }`

`#header #navbar { width:75% }`

This will override any styles that are simply

`#navbar { width:20% }`

This is because in CSS, each level of specificity will gave a style more "weight" to overrule another. (Read http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/04/07/css-specificity-and-inheritance/ or http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/ for more details).

**However,** if there was something like this:

`#navbar { width:20% color:#0f0; }`

Then only the width would be overriden, because there is no style for colour.

Answer (score 0):

CSS is an acronym for Cascading Style Sheets.

If you put the styles for your header at the top of the stylesheet, it won't inherit any of the other styles in the sheet.

Also if your header is a child of an element, it will most likely inherit some of its styles, so make sure to reset them if you need to :)

Comment: The header's CSS is a different file than the main CSS for the page.

Comment: then link to it first in the header section. :)